# Running a rake task with a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have created a rake task that takes an argument. I can run this rake task in the command line using `rake my_task["args"]`.

I'm now trying to create a form with a textfield and a button. When the button is clicked the rake task should run with the content of the textfield as the argument for the task.

How can I get a a rails form (form_tag I believe, it is not related to any resource) to behave in such a way and how can I run a rake task on button click?

I'm not sure what goes where so if you could specify where instructions should be it'll be a huge help for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A rake task is a server script so the pattern you need to follow will look like.

1) User requests a form that has a text field and submit button (controller#new)

2) User hits submit on the form which makes a request to your rails application (controller#create)

3) Controller action runs the rake task using the 'system' method and passes through parameters from the form:

```
class MyController  < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    system "rake my_task", params[:args]
  end
end
```

In your new view you'll use the form_tag to create the form, a text_field_tag for your parameter, and a submit_tag for your button like this

```
<%= form_tag my_rake_task_path, :method => 'post' do %>
   <%= text_field_tag :args %>
   <%= submit_tag "Run Task" %>
<% end %>
```

If you look closely you'll see that the form tag is using a method called my_rake_task_path.  That is a named route helper.  To create that you'll have to add entries into your routes file like

```
get 'rake_task', to: 'mycontroller#new'
post 'rake_task', to: 'mycontroller#create', :as => 'my_rake_task'
```

If you want to know more about running rake tasks in your controller check out this railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/127-rake-in-background

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking for.